# SIP C++ documentation

Tags: python, python-sip

I have a project in Python which uses SIP to create python wrappers on top of some custom C++ code. Is there any tool which is smart enough to automatically read SIP specification and generate documentation for the Python classes?
I have tried pdoc and doxygen. I want suggestions before I move onto Sphinx.